# Forces acting on baseball question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

I got a question wrong on my homework and am not sure why:

> You hit a baseball with a bat and it flies into left field. We are looking for forces that act on the baseball starting right before you hit the baseball up until right after it hits the ground. Are the following forces acting **on the baseball**?
>
> The force from the ground on the ball - **YES**
>
> The force of you on the ball - **NO**

I said yes to both of them because everything has a gravitational pull/force on everything else, even though this pull might be small. I don't think that this was the correct line of thinking. Why is the answer to the first question "yes" while the second is "no?" Is it because the ball does hit the ground in the question but the person never directly touches the baseball?

Comment: Yeah I don't think the question was considering the gravitational attraction between you and the ball.